# Distinguished category of groups, is it abelian?

Tags: category-theory, modules

Let $\mathcal{A}$ denote the following category. The objects of $\mathcal{A}$ are the pairs $(H,G)$ where $G$ is an abelian group and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.
The morphisms between $(H,G)$ and $(H',G')$ is the set $\{f \in \operatorname{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}}(G,G'): f(H) \subseteq H'\}$. Is this an abelian category?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Let $G$ be any non-zero abelian group. Then the obvious morphism $(0,G)\to (G,G)$ is a monomorphism and epimorphism, but not an isomorphism, which can't happen in an abelian category.